# .Net MemoryCache - How to update expiration time for an existing item?

Tags: .net, caching, memorycache

Memcached API has a Touch() method, which updates the expiration policy for a given key. How do I best accomplish this with the .Net ObjectCache class?

The best I could see would be to remove the object and re-add with a new expiration, but obviously that is sub optimal performance wise.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to reset cache item duration.

However, because it is an in-memory cache (not distributed like memcached), get and re-add is fast, like passing references.

One other option is to use a SlidingExpiration for your cache item.